# asteriskwin32 and WS

Tags: voip, sip, asterisk, sip-server

Can asteriskwin32 be installed on a windows service 2008? I am asking this because in my case i couldn't install it. I have a bash.exe error. I don;t know how to solve the problem

If asteriskwin32 is not compatible with WS2008 are there other solutions for a SIP server PBX (including registar server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:
http://www.myvoipapp.com/
http://www.3cx.com/phone-system/

Comment: thx frank but i need a free licence server - like asterisk. i would like though to use asterisk:). can you give me some tips on how to install it?

Comment: i would personally never recommend to use asterisk server on windows. the best solution would be to use linux based asterisk solution.

Comment: my requirements were to use sip server for windows (a free source code). i found asteriskwin32 and tested it localy. it works ok. i have though problems when installing it on windows service 2008:(. don't know what to do. appreciate for your help